# jQuery and cheerio, selecting links that contain a word in either the href OR text?

Tags: jquery, node.js, npm

is there a way in jquery to select all links that contain a certain word in the href OR the link text?  (the same word in either)?  Please comment a way to select that cheerio can interpret as well, I am using node and cheerio with NPM to create a scraper that needs to iterate over all links on a page and find if "shirts" is inside either the link itself or the text related to the link.  I then need to request HTML for any of those links and scrape it for certain data.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').each(function() { // Go through all links
    if ($(this).text() == "LINK TEXT") { // Change text to whatever you want to compare
        // Do what you want with links having certain text
    }
    if ($(this).attr("href") == "HREF VALUE") { // Change href to whatever you want to compare
        // Do what you want with links having certain href
    }
});
```

This checks all links for the specified text and/or href.